# Can't store certain chinese characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf8mb4

I'm importing csv files to MySQL using LOAD DATA with CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4. This workes well most often, but from time to time I still get errors like this:

> ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '楽天市場をみ'

It seems like if there are still some chinese characters that don't work and I have no idea why. Are these characters outside of utf8mb4? How can this be handled?

Edit: When opening the csv with notepad++ there seem to be an "invisible" part after the chinese letters, not sure if this is the reason or the chinese letters before: 楽天市場をみxE3x82

Comment: Is your column NVARCHAR type ?

Comment: If `xE3x82` represents the Unicode character `E382` then this is in a range that is termed a `Private Use Area` and can contain propriety Unicode characters that are determined by the specific need (i.e. it can contain anything that a vendor decides to use it for). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas

Comment: You're right, xE3x82 is the reason. Is there any way to make MySQL ignore those characters (or lines) in the import csv file? I'm importing these files with millions of lines and I would like to avoid any "pre-processing" to eliminate those characters, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Is anything in the data-flow limiting that column to 20 *bytes*?  `E38292` is `を`; `E382` seems to be a truncated UTF-8 character.  I interpret `楽天市場をみxE3x82` as 6 well-formed 3-byte characters, plus 2 more bytes, hence 20.

I think the problem (and possible 20-byte limit) happened *before* creating the CSV file.